# Error uploading asset to Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to upload a simple shapefile to my assets in Google Earth Engine (GEE). Since I started studying GEE I found these errors when uploading some .shp files:

"Error: Multiple primary files found."; and

"Error: Could not unzip file."

Both errors happened to the same asset, and also for some other assets.

All .shp and auxiliary files were compressed to .zip

These are the files I got compressed + the .zip file itself:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In a single upload, you must upload **exactly one** shapefile `.shp`, and its auxiliary files (`.shx`, `.dbf`, `.prj`, and so on). You cannot upload multiple shapefiles at once.

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the files that I compressed.